# Is there a way to clone all api of a site like https://www.food2fork.com/ to save it on my own server to continue use in future

Tags: java, python, web, clone

The site food to fork served a lot, now it's going to be shutdown soon. So is there a way to clone all its data so we can made it public for all user.

Comment: An API is not data. An API is an interface to interact with software. if you want to "clone an API", you must obtain a copy of the software.

Comment: Have you looked at https://archive.org to see if any of the data was saved there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no there isn't a way to harvest all of the content of an arbitrary site via its API.

In the specific case of fork2food, what you are proposing to do would be a violation of the [terms and conditions](https://www.food2fork.com/about/terms) of the site.

This matters even if the site is about to close.  The content of the site may still have commercial value to the site owners *or the people that they owe money to*.  If you were to copy that content and serve it out of your own server, you are diminishing the value of *their* intellectual property.

If your intentions are good, my advice would be to contact the site owners directly and make them an offer (e.g. money) to buy the intellectual property.